# How to refer to multiple class name with a same variable?

Tags: vb.net, class

How can i refer to multiple name with a same variable?

i wrote this code

```
Public Shared Function drag()
        Dim drag As Boolean, mousex As Integer, mousey As Integer
        If drag Then
            Me.Top = Cursor.Position.Y - mousey
            Me.Left = Cursor.Position.X - mousex
        End If
    End Function
```

and another code to move windows form with no borders and i want to use this function with all classes and form but i get this error

'Me' is valid only within an instance method.

with which keyword can i replace "Me" to make it work with any form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By passing the value of the relevant control or form in as part of the routine. In the example below, I use a control - amend to suit your circumstances.

```
Public Shared Function drag(ByVal theControl As Control)
    Dim drag As Boolean, mousex As Integer, mousey As Integer
    If drag Then
        theControl.Top = Cursor.Position.Y - mousey
        theControl.Left = Cursor.Position.X - mousex
    End If
End Function
```

However, there is another problem with your function - you are using a function but not returning any values. Always have `Option Strict On` to help with strong programming practices. Also, you declare `drag`, `mouseX` and `mouseY` in your routine but you do not initialise them - so they are by default false or 0 and you never drag anything.

Your routine structure should be:

```
Public Shared Sub drag(ByVal theControl As Control) ' and whatever other parameters should be included
     '...
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you so much it worked great and thank you for all remarks

Comment: @omarissa. Glad I can help - the custom in Stack Exchange is to mark the answer as accepted by the tick mark on the left of the answer.

Comment: @Mary: Hence my revised structure in the latter part of the post. Hence why I also said "However, there is another problem with your function - you are using a function but not returning any values".